# How to close WKWebView via javascript on the site?

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I have a finished application. I can not implement the closure of VKWebView from registration at the end of registration. Since I have not encountered this in the lens - p.

WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];

```
        WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
        webView.navigationDelegate = self;
        webView.customUserAgent = "Cron";
        [self.view addSubview:webView];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myUrl"]];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Hi @A can yo explain a little more in detail what do you need to know? Reading your question, I am understanding that you want to close an iOS object (WKWebView) from Javascript, but it seems not to be clear enough.

Comment: In Kotlin, for example, I can pass a function to the interface, a function that closes the WebView when I need to do it using js. And how it happens in the objectivist - с I don’t understand.

Answer (score 0):

in order to interact with the WKWebView, you can use the javascript functions for them.

After the WKWebView has finished loading (via delegate for example), yo can use the evaluateJavascript functions, to trigger any event in the web or in your iOS code.

For example:

```
[self.webview evaluateJavaScript:@"var foo = 1; foo + 1;" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil)
    {
        if (result != nil)
        {
            NSInteger integerResult = [result integerValue]; // 2
            NSLog(@"result: %d", integerResult);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

The javascript function is:

```
var foo = 1; foo + 1;
```

There you can set any javascript function from objective-c side, or call any function in the web side.

For example, if you have a javascript function in your web site called:

```
func closeWeb()
```

You have to set the function like this:

```
[self.webview evaluateJavaScript:@"closeWeb();" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil)
       // Code for success
    } else {
        NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Comment: it turns out that from objective - с I call js, but I need it the other way around)

Comment: Yes, it is in the same way than Kotlin, this is the function in javascritpt: var foo = 1; foo + 1; Look at the edit in the answer please.

Comment: aaa) Thanks a lot))

Comment: You're welcome dude... if you found useful the answer please up vote it or mark it as right answer. Thant will help other users too.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. It is necessary for js to call the objective function - с. And not a function that is written in the form of js.

Comment: How to call an Objective-C method from Javascript

Comment: You can not call directly from js, you have to evaluate the web to look for it. When you evaluate a function in javascript like "closeWeb()" you can return a "result" or an "error", in the part where says "Code for success" you can evaluate the result and fire any objective-c function or code.